# Enumerate over unique enum cases ignoring associated value

Tags: swift, indexing, enums

I want to achieve fast enumeration so that I can express this enum as a contiguous monotonic sequence of unique integer values, one for each case (starting at zero). I want the order of assignments to be in the same order as they appear in the declaration.

In this particular example, the sequence would simply be 0, 1 and 2. Is there an expression I can use to achieve this? Or is it only possible by manually typing out this by hand?

I want to have two hashable implementations, so I can establish all possible varieties or simply how many cases I have.

```swift
enum Score: {

    case snap(Rank) // 6 varieties
    case double(Power) // 4 varieties
    case highFive

    var value: Int {
        // ...
    }
}

enum Rank: Int {
//..
}

enum Power: Int {
// ..
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to accomplish here, why a sequence of integers for your enum? How would you connect the sequence to your enum cases?

Comment: How this is done is exactly my question. Let's assume I have a good reason @JoakimDanielson

Comment: I asked because sometimes when you don’t fully understand the purpose of the question it is difficult to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible.

I either choose to maintain two enums that are identical except one has associated types and the other does not.

Or I manually implement the solution.

#### Manual

So for a poker game, I would establish an order of importance for each hand, as per the rules of Texas Hold'em.

```swift
private extension Hand {
    
    var precedence: Int {
        switch self {
        case .highCard:
            return 0
        case .pair:
            return 1
        case .twoPair:
            return 2
        case .threeKind:
            return 3
        case .straight:
            return 4
        case .fourKind:
            return 5
        case .flush:
            return 6
        case .fullHouse:
            return 7
        case .straightFlush:
            return 8
        case .royalFlush:
            return 9
        }
    }
}
```

When the above is in place, I can then produce a toggle.

```swift
extension Hand: CaseIterable {
    
    public static var allCases: [Self] {
        let ranks = Rank.allCases
        return ranks.map(highCard) +
        ranks.map(pair) +
        ranks.map(twoPair) +
        ranks.map(threeKind) +
        ranks.map(straight) +
        ranks.map(fourKind) +
        ranks.map(flush) +
        ranks.map(fullHouse) +
        ranks.map(straightFlush) +
        [royalFlush]
    }
    
    /// Establish every unique case.
    /// - Parameter ignore: If true, do not unique by rank.
    /// - Returns: Every possible case, with or without rank as a uniquing restriction.
    public static func allCases(ignoringRank: Bool) -> [Self] {
        switch ignoringRank {
        case true:
            var tally = Set<Int>()
            return Self.allCases.filter {
                switch tally.contains($0.precedence) {
                case true:
                    return false
                case false:
                    tally.insert($0.precedence)
                    return true
                }
            }
        case false:
            return Self.allCases
        }
    }
}
```

The following is now possible.

```swift
private extension Hand {

    static var assessments: [Assessable.Type] {
        allCases(ignoringRank: true).map {
            $0.assessment
        }
    }

    private var assessment: Assessable.Type {
        switch self {
        case .highCard:
            return HighCardAssessor.self
        case .pair:
            return PairAssessor.self
        case .twoPair:
            return TwoPairAssessor.self
        case .threeKind:
            return ThreeKindAssessor.self
        case .straight:
            return StraightAssessor.self
        case .fourKind:
            return FourKindAssessor.self
        case .flush:
            return FlushAssessor.self
        case .fullHouse:
            return FullHouseAssessor.self
        case .straightFlush:
            return StraightFlushAssessor.self
        case .royalFlush:
            return RoyalFlushAssessor.self
        }
    }
}
```

> An assessor is a type that implements `evaluate(cards:)` to determine if a hand exists. So being able to loop like this is useful.